# How to change with shortcuts (only keyboard no mouse) the type of color in css files (rgb, hsl, hex)? vscode

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, colors, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to know if is there any way to change, with shortcuts (no use of mouse) the type of color in css inside vscode. The [color picker in vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_16#_color-picker-in-html) is very good, that allows you to change from rgb, to hsl to hex with click. But i want to do that without the mouse, [like this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IronLu233.vscode-color-exchange) or something very similar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this possible, there do not appear to be any relevant commands to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a extension that do that, is this the [Change Color Format](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbugh.change-color-format)